# UNICODE_STRING Blue Screen of Death WDK

Tags: c++, wdk

I am working on a Filter Driver as of now, and it has a UNICODE_STRING, allocated as:

```
const SIZE_T buffSize = sizeof(UNICODE_STRING) + NTSTRSAFE_UNICODE_STRING_MAX_CCH * sizeof(wchar_t);
PUNICODE_STRING extracted_key = (PUNICODE_STRING)MmAllocateNonCachedMemory(buffSize);
extracted_key->Length = 0;
extracted_key->MaximumLength = NTSTRSAFE_UNICODE_STRING_MAX_CCH * sizeof(wchar_t);
extracted_key->Buffer = (PWCH)((PCCH)extracted_key + sizeof(UNICODE_STRING));
```

It has value of Key of registry a program is using, e.g.

```
\REGISTRY\A\{0585F053-FB9C-4EAE-BF42-F1FFB9A13ACE}\ActivatableClassId\CortanaUI.AppX4bsqm82t4x1h6fxzn912f92v3hcmq9bb.mca
```

I wanted to remove the prefix of the key which is `\REGISTRY\A\`, calculation of it length was done and I removed it using

```
extracted_key->Length -= (USHORT)length * sizeof(WCHAR); 
extracted_key->MaximumLength -= (USHORT)length * sizeof(WCHAR);
extracted_key->Buffer += length;
```

The extracted_key has to passed to `RtlCompareUnicodeString` and `FsRtlIsNameInExpression` but after sometime, it results in a [BSOD](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WnmWOlWKuXZSJH6ussR07D_SR4MUES77/view?usp=sharing), only on Windows 7. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `sizeof(UNICODE_STRING)` are you sure? Is it something like  `wchar_t UNICODE_STRING[] = "\REGISTRY\A\{0585F053-FB9C-4EAE-BF42-F1FFB9A13ACE}\....;`. Because if it is `const wchar_t* UNICODE_STRING = "...` sizeof gives you a size of a pointer, i.e. `sizeof(wchar_t*)` instead of string size in bytes.

Comment: You can replace it with [wcslen](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/wcslen/)(UNICODE_STRING) * sizeof(wchar_t)

Comment: UNICODE_STRING is defined in [WDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wudfwdm/ns-wudfwdm-_unicode_string). It requires a Buffer in it, both are allocated simultaneously and Buffer is set to memory after the structure.

Comment: Don't initialize `UNICODE_STRING`s yourself use [`RtlUnicodeStringInitEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntstrsafe/nf-ntstrsafe-rtlunicodestringinitex). In fact don't modify the `UNICODE_STRING` yourself either use the methods in [`ntstrsafe.h`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntstrsafe/)

Comment: Not initialized by me, Allocated then RtlCopyUnicodeString and RtlAppendUnicodeStringToString was used....

Comment: @MianBilawal I'm going off the code posted, which is as best I can tell from the docs... not safe because it's manually allocating one.